# GitBucket で GUI上で .md ファイルを編集したとき，全角文字が ? に変換されてしまう

Tags: gitbucket

### 問題の要約

GitBucket のリポジトリの README.md を GUI上の edit ボタンを押して編集したときの問題です．

このときに全角文字を記入すると，プレヴュー時には問題ないのですが，commit したときにすべて ? に置き換えられてしまいます．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

原因は不明ですが，解決策がわかりました．

ローカルにテキストエディタで `.md` ファイルを作成し，アップロードします．

そうすると，全角文字が正しく表示されます．

不思議なのですが，一度上記の手続きを行うともうそれ以降そのファイルを edit ボタンから編集しても， ? に変化する現象は起こらなくなるようです．